# Zope logging with WSGI

Tags: logging, wsgi, zope

Since version 4, by default Zope is served via WSGI. Instances created with the *mkwsgiinstance* command do not create log files when they run.

How can I enable logging like in ZServer for WSGI?

I found this in the Zope 4 docs: *"The runwsgi commands takes a PasteDeploy configuration file as its argument. You can configure different WSGI capable servers, the WSGI pipeline or logging configuration in this file."*

So I guess my question should be specifically: How do I configure logging in the zope.ini for the default WSGI server in Zope (waitress)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a zope.ini that works for the default WSGI-server in Zope 4 (waitress). As with ZServer, it creates an access-log (Z4.log) and an event-log (event.log) in the instance's log-directory.

```
[app:zope]
use = egg:Zope#main
zope_conf = %(here)s/wsgi.conf

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 8080

[filter:translogger]
use = egg:Paste#translogger
setup_console_handler = False

[pipeline:main]
pipeline =
    egg:Zope#httpexceptions
    translogger
    zope

[loggers]
keys = root, waitress, wsgi

[handlers]
keys = console, accesslog, eventlog

[formatters]
keys = generic, message

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s
datefmt = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

[formatter_message]
format = %(message)s

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console

[logger_waitress]
level = INFO
handlers = eventlog
qualname = waitress

[logger_wsgi]
level = WARN
handlers = accesslog
qualname = wsgi
propagate = 0

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[handler_accesslog]
class = FileHandler
args = ('%(here)s/../log/Z4.log','a')
level = INFO
formatter = message

[handler_eventlog]
class = FileHandler
args = ('%(here)s/../log/event.log', 'a')
level = INFO
formatter = generic
```

I got it mostly from [here](https://github.com/plone/plone.recipe.zope2instance/pull/76/files/f69c3998274306c92ed5317d2c0e5918f3f4e25c#diff-213984d4032c2000cafba94d0b5b2d33) but had to make some adjustments.